# oracle % wild card in function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to compare two varchar2 columns (HOME, AWAY) with a parameter p_search_string but with a % wild card. When I sent just few first letters I want to find all columns HOME or AWAY with that three first letters.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SEARACH_FOR_GAMES (p_search_string in varchar2, p_match_type in number)
                             return weak_cur
  IS
    SEARCH_FIXID WEAK_CUR;   
  BEGIN  
  OPEN   SEARCH_FIXID FOR

     select FIXID, HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME 
       from SOCCER_PREMATCH_MATCHES s
      where upper(s.HOME) LIKE upper('%'p_search_string'%') 
         or upper(s.AWAY) LIKE upper('%'p_search_string'%')
        AND p_match_type IN (0, 2)
```

I tried few ways but I'm getting errors that II expecting, or some similar errors ..

Comment: If you are searching for HOME or AWAY with the *first* three letters xyz, you should use `p_search_string||'%'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate wildcard with string using `upper('%' || p_search_string || '%')`